# Solve the recursion $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ with $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> For $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ for $n \ge 2$ with $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 3$, determine an explicit form for $f(n)$.

First, we shift the indices such that

$$f(n+2) = 2f(n+1) + f(n),$$

which is equivalent to

$$f(n+2) - 2f(n+1) - f(n) = 0$$

Thus, we receive the polynomial

$$q(z) = 1 - 2z - z^2$$

Since it's hard to determine the roots from this expression, we take a look at the reflected polynomial

$$q^R(z) := z^2 + 2z - 1 = (z+1)^2 - 2$$

which needs to have the same roots as $q(z)$. We now see that the roots are

$$q_1 = -1 - \sqrt 2 $$
$$q_2 = -1 + \sqrt 2$$

Now, we can write the explicit form of $f(n)$ as

$$f(n) = a(-1-\sqrt 2) + b(-1+\sqrt 2)n$$

with $a, b$ being coefficients that we yet have to find. Herefore we use the conditions from the start:

$$f(0) = a(-1-\sqrt 2) = 1,$$

which means that

$$a = {1 \over {-1-\sqrt 2}}$$

Thus, we have

$$f(1) = {{1 \over {-1-\sqrt 2}}(-1-\sqrt 2) - b(1-\sqrt 2)} = 3$$

which yields

$$b = {-2 \over {1 - \sqrt 2}}$$

In the end, we receive

$$f(n) = 1 + 2n$$

Is this the way to do it?

Comment: You forgot the exponents $$f(n)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^{n+1}+\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{n+1}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I don't see how you did conclude this form of $f(n)$. Following my book, the exponents should be just $n$. Besides that, where does that $1/2$ come from?

Comment: I found the answer using *Mathematica* and not by hand: this is why I wrote it in a comment and not in a regular answer :) I mean: it's not fair to use it as a solution, but just as a reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial for this recursion is $q(z)=z^2-2z-1$ with roots $z_1=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $z_2=1-\sqrt{2}$. So the explicit formula for $f(n)$ takes the form $$f(n)=a(1+\sqrt{2})^n+b(1-\sqrt{2})^n, n\geq 0.$$ Now use the initial conditions $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=3$ in the above form to get two linear equations in two unknowns $a$ and $b$. Solve them to get the values of $a=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$,  $b=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and so the solution for the recursion.

Comment: Thanks, now I see where I was mistaken!